# Text to object with JS in simple way

Tags: javascript, object, parsing

I wrote simple script that make an object from some formatted text. It works, but for me, it seems a little complicated. May be you can advise more a simpler way?

```js
let myText = document.getElementById('element').innerText; //get text from div
let myObj = {};
let arrText = myText.replaceAll('\n', '').split(';') //split text
let monthesCodes = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

arrText.forEach(element => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if (element.includes(monthesCodes[i])) {
      let arrString = element.split(' – ') //split line one by one by '-'
      if (!myObj.hasOwnProperty(i + 1)) { //if there are no key with month nomber in object - create it
        myObj[i + 1] = {}
      }
      let keyDay = arrString[0].replace(' ' + monthesCodes[i], '').replaceAll('and', ',') //left only numbers and delimeters in left part of string
      if (keyDay.includes(',')) { //if the left part have delimeters write in sub-object a key (number) with the value as name of the holiday
        for (let keyDays of keyDay.split(',')) {
          myObj[i + 1][+keyDays] = arrString[1];
        }
      } else { //else if we have only one number in left string
        myObj[i + 1][keyDay] = arrString[1];
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log(myObj)
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="element">
    <br>1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 8 January – NY hollidays;
    <br>7 January – Orthodox Christmas;
    <br>23 February – Man's day;
    <br>8 March – Woman's Day;
    <br>1 May – Labor Day;
    <br>9 May – Memorial Day;
    <br>12 June – Country Day;
    <br>4 November – People uniting day
  </div>
</body>
```

Output

```js
{
  "1": {
    "1": "NY hollidays",
    "2": "NY hollidays",
    "3": "NY hollidays",
    "4": "NY hollidays",
    "5": "NY hollidays",
    "6": "NY hollidays",
    "7": "Orthodox Christmas",
    "8": "NY hollidays"
  },
  "2": {
    "23": "Man's day"
  },
  "3": {
    "8": "Woman's Day"
  },
  "5": {
    "1": "Labor Day",
    "9": "Memorial Day"
  },
  "6": {
    "12": "Country Day"
  },
  "11": {
    "4": "People uniting day"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your script does (or supposed is to do). _"make an object from some formatted text"_ is not really meaningful.

Comment: If it works then this is a topic for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Let me know if you're going to delete this and put it in code review, I'll post my answer there.

Comment: If you fix the comments that Andreas have made, we'll take it over at Code Review. No need to delete anything. It could be as much as a simple sentence explaining what prompted you to write this and what it is exactly. It looks like a formatter for holidays of sorts, but most people go from an object to HTML, not the other way around. Fix it first, we'll migrate it after. Thank you.

Comment: What should happen if you have two events on the same day? Or is that not possible?

Comment: Yes, it's better place this to Code Review.

Comment: @Ben Stephens, it's a list of public holidays. So only once.

Comment: @Andreas, I have a list of public holidays from goverment site. My aim is to create a calendar with formatting holiday days. I chose an algorithm of checking keys in the object   on dom creating stage. So for that I need text ->to object

Answer (score 1):

I think that separating the part of the code where you get the info from the strings from the part where this gets organised into the object should help in understanding as you can focus more on the details of what each part is doing:

```js
const event_listings = document.getElementById('element').innerText
  .replaceAll('\n', '').split(';');
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

const parse_event_listing = (string) => {
  const [date_info, title] = string.split(' – ');
  let date_parts = date_info.replace(/,/g, '').replace(' and', '').split(' ');
  const month = date_parts.pop();
  
  return [months.indexOf(month) + 1 + '', date_parts, title];
};

const myObj = event_listings
  .map(parse_event_listing)
  .reduce(
    (acc, [month, days, title]) => Object.assign(acc, {
      [month]: Object.assign(
        acc[month] || {},
        Object.fromEntries(days.map((d) => [d, title]))
      )
    }), {}
  );

console.log(myObj);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="element">
    <br>1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 8 January – NY hollidays;
    <br>7 January – Orthodox Christmas;
    <br>23 February – Man's day;
    <br>8 March – Woman's Day;
    <br>1 May – Labor Day;
    <br>9 May – Memorial Day;
    <br>12 June – Country Day;
    <br>4 November – People uniting day
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that uses `reduce()`, `filter()`, some simple `regex` and array manipulation. The benefit (I think) is one: it spits out the data in 2 different usable formats and two: it is easier to read

It first compiles a tidy array of objects, each having

```
{
 month: month name,
 event: event name,
 dates: list of dates associated
}
```

That might be useful to have the data in that format. But it then takes that and runs it through a `map()` to format it the way you have in your example.

```js
let myText = document.getElementById('element').innerText; //get text from div
let arrText = myText.replaceAll('\n', '').split(';') //split text
let months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
let event_list = arrText.reduce((acc, a) => {
  let nums = a.replace("and", ",").replace(/[^,\d.-]/g, "").split(",");
  let month = months.filter(m => a.includes(m));
  let event = a.split("–")[1].trim();
  acc.push({
    event: event,
    month: month[0],
    dates: nums.join(",")
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(event_list)

// now the same format you have

let event_list2 = {};
event_list.map(obj => {
  let monthnum = months.indexOf(obj.month) + 1;
  if (!event_list2.hasOwnProperty(monthnum)) event_list2[monthnum] = {};
  obj.dates.split(",").forEach(dt => event_list2[monthnum][dt] = obj.event);
})

console.log(event_list2)
```

```html
<div id="element">
  <br>1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 8 January – NY hollidays;
  <br>7 January – Orthodox Christmas;
  <br>23 February – Man's day;
  <br>8 March – Woman's Day;
  <br>1 May – Labor Day;
  <br>9 May – Memorial Day;
  <br>12 June – Country Day;
  <br>4 November – People uniting day
</div>
```

Comment: _"list of dates associated"_ - Why is that list a string and not an actual list?

Comment: I don't know the OPs intent, other than to field different ways of parsing the text to assemble usable data. In order to reach the OPs format, I thought it was logical to assemble the data structure in the way I did, which lent an opportunity to present it in an alternate format. As to why I didn't make the days as array - no reason. Easily mendable if its an issue.

Comment: @Andreas - I didn't change the format, if you scroll down, you'll see the exact requested format. I only presented an additional format that was an artifact of the approach I used.